npm pulish not including all sub folders
below is the prj folder structure
sub folders with package.json  have nothing to do with main project,
these all are third party libs
when i try npm publish --dry-run its igoring mentioned src folders
note: there is no .npmignore file present
your-project/
├── src/
│   ├── common/
│   │   └── js/
│   │       └── lib/
│   │           ├── subfolder1/   
|   |           |--------src/      // folders not getting included in npm publish
│   │           │        ├── fileA.js 
│   │           │        ├── fileB.js 
│   │           │   └── package.json
│   │           ├── subfolder2/   
|   |           |---------src/    // folders not getting included in npm publish
│   │           │         ├── fileC.js 
│   │           │   └── package.json
│   │           └── ...
│   └── ...
├── README.md
└── package.json

this is package.json
{
  "name": "ui-libraries",
  "version": "1.0.0-dev",
  "private": false,
  "description": "Consolidated UI libraries",
   "scripts": {
     "build": "echo 'No build necessary'"
   },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "files": [
    "src/common/js/lib/**/**/*",
    "README.md"
  ]
}


Apparently npm may take into account the files array from package.json files found in your subfolders. Would that explain this issue?

@rutter but i cannot remove package.json from sub folders as it will be used in another repo

Do you want it to be a single package or both sub directory in itself a package separately ?

@iamsmruti  i want to include alll the files and folders  in single package

If the subfolders have a package.json as well, they are individual packages/apps. So, we are moving into the mono repo setup.
May I know the purpose and what exactly you are trying to make? So, I can help you better.

@iamsmruti  all these are third party libraries, seperating these from core repo to seperate repo these all are getting consolidated and publish to the nexus repo( all of our repos are published here ), after this all these libs will be downloaded to core repo (maven project) bascially i want to publish this as single package
